# Another EMF files damaged during PDF export in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, export, emf, wmf

I have some Word to PDF export issues related to `.emf` images, with this [discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/790789/emf-files-damaged-during-pdf-export-in-microsoft-word) directly relating to my problem and appears to be the deepest post about this topic.

I have a similar issue with my phD document in Win10 v2004 using Office 365 and Acrobat DC:

- I use OriginLab objects inserted in a PowerPoint doc that I export as `.emf` files; Save as PDF and Print file as PDF [Adobe and PrimoPDF] works properly for images, however several issues prevent me from using this method, such as not updating page numbers classified with Word sections (it's a mess), crossed-references, etc. 
   [image: Save As .emf]
- The only way to get a high fidelity PDF is to use the built-in module to export the document as PDF, however `.emf` images receive a serious quality loss, coupled with disappearing text boxes since they are usually objects and text boxes grouped in a single `.emf` image 
   [image: Built-in *.emf]
- `.wmf` file export from PPT does not work, as objects are not shown, replaced with a blank square with text, so I cannot replace an `.emf` with a `.wmf`. The same occurs when trying to convert `.emf` to `.wmf` through Inkscape. 
   [image: Inkscape *.wmf]

Any ideas?

- Opening one by one in Origin and exporting as `.wmf` is not preferable as there are too many figures

Comment: Word in Microsoft Office 365 should be able to [work with .svg files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c), if that is an option. (Moments later... I just tried it, and it worked for me.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thanks but that did not solve the issue. Another problem arises, similar to the .emf quality loss. Sorry that I don't know how to upload a picture in a comment, but essentially it becomes a pixelated image.

Comment: * Need to say that now the problem is with PPT, as it exports a bad quality .svg file... If I find how to improve it, this may be solved!

Comment: Sadly, no program (PPT, Inkscape, Imagemagick Display) nor converting website can successfully transform my `.emf` files into `.svg` images :(
No clue about `.svg` files and why PowerPoint can't export them properly...

Comment: @SergioM. It looks to me that if you export as .ai (Adobe Illustrator) files from OriginLab, you should be able to open those in Inkscape and then save to .svg ([How to convert an .ai file to a .svg file?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/116555/129448)).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm sorry to tell that even grouping `.wmf` images in PPT fails to export as `.wmf` files, as figures turn into blank rectangles. I believe that this issue is Office related, since `.svg` files exporting damages the quality (it becomes as rasterized) and `.emf` figures fail to export properly in a built-in application.
PS: `.ai` does not appear to be a integrated extension for image exporting in OriginLab.